# How and where to change add to cart message in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

I am using Magento 2.3.0

[image]

Above message displays when we try to add product more than available quantity from the product detail page. I want to change this error message and want to add a new custom message instead of default one. I tried finding this message but I couldn't find anywhere. So, where can I change this message and which file I have to override?

I want to display the message "The requested QTY for "" exceeds inventory. only x qty available for this product".

NOTE: X is the available qty for the product.

Answer (score 5):

you can add it in your module's `i18n/en_US.csv` file

**"The requested qty is not available","here your custom message"**

Deploy the static content and check

Comment: I have updated my question. can you please check?

Comment: you have to make afterplugin for vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php excute method and need to change this message according to your requirement

Answer (score 3):

You want to update add to cart custom message for exceeds inventory, you have to need override `Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php` file, follow below steps and create custom module for update add to cart custom message for exceeds inventory.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/QtyAddtocartMessage/registration.php

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_QtyAddtocartMessage', __DIR__);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/QtyAddtocartMessage/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_QtyAddtocartMessage" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_InventorySales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/QtyAddtocartMessage/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition" type="Vendor\QtyAddtocartMessage\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition"/>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/QtyAddtocartMessage/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\QtyAddtocartMessage\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition;

use Magento\InventoryReservationsApi\Model\GetReservationsQuantityInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetStockItemDataInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\Data\StockItemConfigurationInterface;

class IsSalableWithReservationsCondition extends \Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition
{
    /**
     * @var GetStockItemDataInterface
     */
    private $getStockItemData;

    /**
     * @var GetReservationsQuantityInterface
     */
    private $getReservationsQuantity;

    /**
     * @var GetStockItemConfigurationInterface
     */
    private $getStockItemConfiguration;

    /**
     * @var ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productSalabilityErrorFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productSalableResultFactory;

    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData
     * @param GetReservationsQuantityInterface $getReservationsQuantity
     * @param GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration
     * @param ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory $productSalabilityErrorFactory
     * @param ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory
     */

    public function __construct(
        GetStockItemDataInterface $getStockItemData,
        GetReservationsQuantityInterface $getReservationsQuantity,
        GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration,
        ProductSalabilityErrorInterfaceFactory $productSalabilityErrorFactory,
        ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
            $this->getStockItemData = $getStockItemData;
            $this->getReservationsQuantity = $getReservationsQuantity;
            $this->getStockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration;
            $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory = $productSalabilityErrorFactory;
            $this->productSalableResultFactory = $productSalableResultFactory;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute(string $sku, int $stockId, float $requestedQty): ProductSalableResultInterface
    {
        $stockItemData = $this->getStockItemData->execute($sku, $stockId);
        if (null === $stockItemData) {
            $errors = [
                $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory->create([
                    'code' => 'is_salable_with_reservations-no_data',
                    'message' => __('The requested sku is not assigned to given stock')
                ])
            ];
            return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => $errors]);
        }

        $availableProductQty = floor($stockItemData['quantity']);
        $product = $this->loadMyProduct($sku);
        $productName = $product->getName();

        /** @var StockItemConfigurationInterface $stockItemConfiguration */
        $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute($sku, $stockId);

        $qtyWithReservation = $stockItemData[GetStockItemDataInterface::QUANTITY] +
            $this->getReservationsQuantity->execute($sku, $stockId);
        $qtyLeftInStock = $qtyWithReservation - $stockItemConfiguration->getMinQty() - $requestedQty;
        $isEnoughQty = (bool)$stockItemData[GetStockItemDataInterface::IS_SALABLE] && $qtyLeftInStock >= 0;
        if (!$isEnoughQty) {
            $errors = [
                $this->productSalabilityErrorFactory->create([
                    'code' => 'is_salable_with_reservations-not_enough_qty',
                    'message' => __('The requested QTY for "%1" exceeds inventory. only %2 qty available for this product.', $productName, $availableProductQty)
                ])
            ];

            return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => $errors]);
        }
        return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => []]);
    }
    public function loadMyProduct($sku)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to to override below classes (Use plugin or preference) , then you can change that message from all sections as per your need:

```
Magento\CatalogInventory\Model
....
class StockStateProvider
```

Line no. 169,221

```
Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition

class IsSalableWithReservationsCondition
```

Line no. 98